# Is it derogatory or offensive to call a detective a dick?

Tags: word-usage, slang, offensive-language, pejorative-language

The word *dick* is generally considered offensive and is marked so in dictionaries. But there is also a meaning of *detective* that it carries. I usually find no derog indication for this meaning.

Is it offensive to call a detective friend of mine a *dick*?

**EDIT** (thanks to Kristina): I want to know if the usage of this word to refer to detectives is offensive in practice, though the dictionaries may opine otherwise. The question is general and not about how I could call my friend :)

Comment: Welcome @Richard! Firstly, you'd have to assume he/she knows that ***"dick"*** means detective, and secondly, whether they would be offended our not would depend on the context in which you use it.  If you said, "Wow!  You *dicks* are always trying to get to the bottom of a mystery, aren't you?", I think your friend might have a clue you were not using the derogatory meaning of ***"dick"***.  If you said, in contrast, "You're such a *dick*!", your friend would most likely misconstrue your meaning.  Still, I think this question might be off-topic unless you bring back some research of your own.

Comment: Thanks Kristina. I have two huge dictionaries at my home and I just checked into them. Please tell me what more research is expected of me, I'll gladly modify the question.

Comment: Pity poor [Dick Tracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Tracy), the butt of many a foul joke.

Comment: The question, as it right now is asking our opinion on whether your friend would be offended by being called a ***"dick"***.  Questions should be answerable and not open for discussion or opinions.  You could try changing the question.  Try including the context in which you are going to use the word - that would help our users.  You can also do research on popularity of certain words using Google's NGram chart: http://books.google.com/ngrams/

Comment: @tchrist, funny! I tried NGram-ing "dick", Dick Tracy and detective to see if there was a pattern of usage during the Dick Tracy era but did not get any useful data.

Comment: Stop calling me Tracy.

Comment: I can't help but laugh. Your name is @Richard. You're a Dick!

Comment: @KristinaLopez `"Wow! You dicks are always trying to get to the bottom of a mystery, aren't you?"` - Not necessarily.  In that case, most people would probably take it as a sarcastic "You _idiots_ are always...", with an implied "and failing".

Comment: @Izkata, with the right inflection, anything can sound sarcastic! Lol!

Comment: [Is it offensive to call a police officer a _cop_](http://forums.officer.com/t74940/), as in "[Cheese it!](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-che4.htm) The cops!"? It's always a matter of context &, when speaking, tone of voice.

Answer (score 7):

While current usage may mark *dick* as offensive ("a man who you think is unpleasant and stupid" per [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dick)), the same entry in Macmillan succinctly summarizes *[dick](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dick)* in the sense of "private detective" as "informal, **old-fashioned**."

In other words, you can use "dick" in this sense if you want to sound like a character from a Mickey Spillane novel, or a *film noir* movie.

Answer (score 7):

If you are wondering whether or not your detective friend will confuse the derogatory form of dick with the slang term for detective, well, that depends on how much currency he holds in the parlance of English slang. As to *dick* being a pejorative for *detective*, that claim is dubious. [Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/090304.html), citing the Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang, has this to say about the word's origin (italics are mine):

> The Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang suggests an entirely different origin *(different from the notion that "dick" is a shortened form of "detective)* for "dick," one that I find very plausible. They trace the noun "dick" in the "detective" sense to the 19th century (around 1864) criminal underworld slang verb "to dick," meaning "to watch." This "dick" came in turn from the Romany (the language of the Gypsies) word "dik," meaning "to look, to see." This is significant because the Gypsies, originally from northern India, played a prominent role in the British underworld in the 18th and 19th centuries, and several Romany words (including "posh") percolated into general English usage during that period. One can easily imagine "dick" meaning "to watch" being transformed into a noun that means "one who watches, a police detective, etc." It is even possible that the popularity of Dick Donovan tales at the time contributed to the spread of the term "dick" among the law-abiding (and mystery-reading) public.

I would also add that, after reading a half dozen Raymond Chandler novels, I don't recall any implied meaning of "dick" that suggests its relationship to the derogatory usage we hear today. The most pejorative implied sense of the word I've taken away from detective fiction comes from the slighting way police officers use the term to refer to dime-a-dozen private eyes. In that way, the word "[shamus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamus)" is also used equally pejoratively.

Comment: "Private Dick" or "Private Eye" would not be out of place today. Of course the "eye" is really the letter i, as in Private Investigator.